# Create managed form Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm building managed solution and created a new form on account. This form is unmanaged and because of that this managed solution can't be deleted from end users crm. Is there a possibility to create managed form in dynamics crm?
I didn't find it in documentation and saw no property in form xml that differ my form from managed ones.
I'm using Dynamics CRM 2016 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working on your solution in your dev environment, all components will be unmanaged.  When you export your solution you are given the option of exporting as managed or unmanaged; choosing managed will result in all components in your solution being managed.

You should distribute the appropriate version based on the need.  For example, to move to a new dev environment, you would import the unmanaged version; when distributing your solution to clients, use the managed version.

Any unmanaged component can be deleted from an environment, so if you are unable to delete your managed solution from an environment, it's probably because of something unrelated to the unmanaged form. If the error message you are getting specifically references the unmanaged form, you could be running into a platform bug (we've encountered quite a few when importing/upgrading/deleting managed solutions).

Comment: Yes. That's true. It appeared that I had different problem. After I unistalled my managed solution, accounts stop loading because they couldn't find than new form that was in solution ( that I got from error log ).